# Path connectedness of the set $S=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2:y=\sin(\frac{1}{x}),0<x\le 1\}.$

Tags: general-topology

We know that any interval of real line $\mathbb R$ is path-connected. Also continuous image of a path-connected space is path-connected. But I am confused about the following set$$S=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2:y=\sin(\frac{1}{x}),0<x\le 1\}.$$

As, $(0,1]$ is path connected and $S$ is a continuous image of $(0,1]$ so $S$ must be path-connected.

But , in all books of Topology it is proved that $S$ is NOT path-connected.

So, where my mistake to understand ?

Comment: You are wrong. This set is path-connected. In all books of topology it is proved that its closure $\bar{S}$ is connected and not path-connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $S$ you specify *is* path-connected.
However, $$S\cup(\{0\}\times[-1,1])$$ is *not* path-connected (it is connected, though).